# how to record video with mixture of line-in and out?

Tags: video, photo-booth

I want to create a guitar video when I'm playing guitar simultaneously with a track playing. So I want to write mixture of line in and out. Is it possible in Photo Booth? By default, it writes only line-in channel.

Comment: Any reason why you're not using Garage Band to track the sound after recording the video of you playing? You do need to have a cue noise to assist in syncing the tracks, but for songs less than 20 minutes, time skew rarely can be measured let alone detract from the final mix with modern digital recording tools.

Comment: So as far as I understand you offer to do the following: (1) record a video with my line-in sound using PhotoBooth, (2) extract audio from the video and mixture it with sound track in GarageBand, (3) add result back to the video. In this case the question is how to get audio from video and put it back using mac programs

Comment: Gladly (for us both), my way is more work than using Soundflower as described below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Install [Soundflower](http://cycling74.com/soundflower-landing-page/)
- Open QuickTime Player and choose File > Movie Recording
- Change the input device to Soundflower (2ch)

  [image]
- Create a new project in Garageband
- Set the output device to Soundflower (2ch) in the preferences

  [image]
- Add one audio track for the background audio and another for recording the guitar
- Enable playthru for both tracks

  [image]
- Start recording in QuickTime Player and Garageband

Answer (score 1):

There is a way if you have an audio interface. Plug your music (likely via a phone) into one channel and your instrument into another. Photobooth will pick up both.